# Hook with session plugin?

Tags: bottle

How to use hook in bottle?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle-session/0.4

I am trying to implement session plug in with bottle hook.

```
    @bottle.route('/loginpage')
    def loginpage():
  return '''
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        Username: <input name="username" type="text" />
        Password: <input name="password" type="password" />
        <input value="Login" type="submit" />
    </form>
'''

@bottle.route('/login', method='POST')
def do_login(session, rdb):
    username = request.forms.get('username')
    password = request.forms.get('password')
    session['name'] = username
    return session['name']


@bottle.route('/usernot')
def nextPage(session):
return session['name']
```

and below is my hook:

```
@hook('before_request')
def setup_request():
try:
    request.session = session['name']
    request.session.cookie_expires = False
    response.set_cookie(session['name'], "true")
    #request.session.save()
except Exception, e:
    print ('setup_request--> ', e)
```

I am unable to access session in hook, is it possible to pass session as a parameter to hook?

Comment: If your question has nothing to do with django/flask etc then you shouldn't tag it as such. You should also describe the problems you are having.

Comment: sorry bro, thought if the guy knows about Django or flask he might have knowledge on bottle aslo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
request.get_cookie("bottle.session") #if you haven't changed the default cookie name ...
```

Comment: can i have the full code for this scenario, i need a login system with before and after hook.

Comment: I don't have such code :). start with printing request.get_cookie("bottle.session") and go from there

Answer (score 0):

If you use the session beaker, the one mentioned and described in bottle recipes:

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html

You can access the session in hook like this:

```
http_session = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
```

it works smoothly. Have you considered to change it?